# Test Driven JavaScript Development with Django vs Node.js

Tags: javascript, django, node.js, tdd, karma-runner

I have a web project coded 80% in JavaScript and 20% in Django without a single unit testing as I rushed for Minimum Marketing Features. Now that the project is getting funded, I decided to invest some time to introduce TDD. I had a great deal of inspiration from this KickStarter-funded tutorial.

http://www.letscodejavascript.com/

The author uses Node.js, Jake, Lint, Nodeunit, and Karma to simplify the whole integration process. The server/client tests in all major browsers is done in a single command and I was really hooked to this idea, but it requires switching to Node.js.

I've searched for TDD in Django and ran into this tutorial that makes use of Selenium.

http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com/

However this TDD was primarily based on unit testing in server. Here are the questions.

- Can multiple client JavaScript testing be done in Django/Python?

I assume the answer is no since js files are nothing more than static library in Django. Correct me if I'm wrong.

- Is it worth using Node.js just for the sake of TDD Javascript?

My logic was either you use Python or Node.js for the server, but since tools like Karma and Buster.js requires Node.js, I was wondering whether setting up the Node.js alongside Django just for multiple client testing is plausible choice when considering lower cost of maintenance.

Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at using selenium in your django test suite. [Django's official docs cover this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/) in moderate detail

To answer your question about Node.js - I would say that it's probably not worth the complexity to add node.js SOLELY for the purpose of running unit tests. Also, since your javascript is likely built to run in a browser, it's less likely that things will break down if you use a tool like selenium (which runs the code in an actual browser, providing a python scripting interface).

Comment: The project is an online document editor (with some twist) and comes with logic beyond simple DOM manipulation, which I don't think can be tested using Selenium. I was hoping for something like creating a test suite using QUnit and Selenium could run this suite on multiple clients. If all else fails, I can always manually run the test on each browser but so far I have only seen this one-for-all solution in Node.js

Comment: selenium absolutely *can* run qunit tests and check the results